# Installing plugins on IIS-hosted site

Tags: installation, iis

I've got a Windows 2008r2 server with IIS which is hosting a wordpress site. However, I can't get installations of plugins to work with FTP. This is what I've done:

- I've set up a FTP site in IIS which has it's root in the `wordpress/` directory
- I've created a user which has the "Full Access" priviledge on the entire wordpress directory.
- When I log in using a ftp program or browser, it works fine, I can browse the wordpress dirs, upload files etc.

But when I try to install a plugin, it takes a *long* time, and then errors out with "Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content).". Googling suggests this would be because the ftp root is not in the same directory as the `wp-content` dir, but it is. It does not seem to be a credential problem either, because giving wrong password/username/hostname gives an error quickly. I can also see the ftp session in the IIS manager.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of your wp-config.php file insert the following code;

```
if(is_admin()) {
add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

Save then try again